# How to find a Date in a Column, return a row number location as an integer, then store as a variable to subtract dates

Tags: excel, vba, string, integer

Trying to come up with a way to search for a date in a column, return the row number, then store it as an integer in which I could subtract an integer from the date found to give me a new value.  Such as 539 - 1 to give me the specific Date in Column A - Row 538

I've tried referencing a FoundCell function in which it will return the address as a string, but not a value in which I could manipulate it - such as substracting due to the differences in object types. (Date, Range, String)

I feel like I'm on the right path - but just don't know the right syntax to figure this out and googling has not gotten me an answer after searching.

```
    Sub TestFunction()

    Set Wb7 = Workbooks.Open("G:\DATA\......xlsm")

    Set raw5 = Sheets("dailyPnL")
    Set Wb7 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set raw5 = ActiveSheet

    RowOutputFile2 = Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row
```

'This gives me the last date row value which is 539 in this case.
'I want to be able to search for any Date Variable using - 2 as an example to give me row 537 then store it as a new variable / starting point.

```
    Dim WHAT_TO_FIND As Date
    Dim FoundCell As Range  
    Dim FindCell As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim TestAddress As Range


    WHAT_TO_FIND = raw5.Cells(RowOutputFile2, 1)  '=9/27/2019
    Set FoundCell = raw5.Range("A:A").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)
```

'FoundCell = 9/27/2019

```
    With ActiveSheet
    Set FindCell = .Cells.Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)
    End With
    FirstAddress = FindCell.Address
```

'This provides me as a string "$A$539

```
    Set TestAddress = Range(FirstAddress)
```

'Trying to convert TestAddress as a range to provide me with A539 that I could use as a starting point.

'Eventually I want to use the "Found" start date in A539 as my reference point, and substract an Integer from it using the results from another variable.  Such as the difference between Workdays.

```
    Workdays = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(raw3.Cells(RowOutputFile, 1), raw5.Cells(2, 1))
```

'For example this would give me 1 because it's taking the Dates between two spreadsheet and calculating the difference between them in business days.

```
    If Workdays = 1 Then

    New1RowOutputFile = FoundCell - Workdays

    End Sub
```

'This is my goal, to make New1RowOutputFile give me a row number subtracting the Workday Integer.  This would be 539 - 1 = 538.  Now I want the specific date that sits in A538 which would translated as the new "New1RowOutputFile" .

I get a bunch of different syntax errors switching between Dates, Ranges, and Integers that I just don't know how to do it.  Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested - I found an easy way to do it using match function in VBA.  I was essentially trying to copy a time series of data from one spreadsheet to another - accomodating business day differences.

See function Below:

```
Sub SearchFunction()

Dim raw As Worksheet, raw2 As Worksheet, raw3 As Worksheet, raw5 As Worksheet

Dim NewDates2 As Integer, RowOutputFile As Integer, RowOutputFile2 As Integer 
Dim Wb7 As Workbook, Wb5 As Workbook
Dim NewDates As Long
Dim NewDates3 As Date, TextDate As Date
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range

Set Wb5 = Workbooks.Open("G:\DATA......)
Set raw = Sheets("BarraInputs")
Set raw2 = Sheets("BarraOutputTS")
Set raw3 = Sheets("BarraPerformance")

Set Wb7 = Workbooks.Open("G:\DATA\2......)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set raw5 = Sheets("dailyPnL")


Wb5.Activate
RowOutputFile = Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row

Wb7.Activate
raw5.Activate

RowOutputFile2 = Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row

Dim col_match As Double
col_match = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(raw3.Cells(1, 1), raw5.Range("A:A"), 0)

StartCell = "E" & col_match
StartCell2 = "G" & col_match

DragRange = "E" & col_match & ":E" & RowOutputFile2
DragRange2 = "G" & col_match & ":G" & RowOutputFile2

        Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range(DragRange)
        Set Rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range(DragRange2)
        Set Rng3 = Union(Rng1, Rng2)
        Rng3.Copy

        Wb5.Activate
        raw3.Activate

        StartCell3 = "M" & RowOutputFile

        Range(StartCell3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

   End Sub
```